# I Would Like To Have A Single Button Display A Different Line Of Text Each Consecutive Time It's Pressed in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, button

I'm extremely new to coding, so apologies if this question is trivial or the answer is easily found somewhere. I have searched, but I cannot find anything that helps.

Basically, I'm trying to code a simple, 2 button app in Android Studio.

Button1 is meant to simply display a series of commands to the user via text box.

Button2 merely resets.

My problem is, I would like Button1 to change what's displayed in the text view each time it is pressed, but I cannot figure out how to do so. I don't want to make 6 or 7 buttons.

Basically I would like it to run as follows;

Text = "Pick a number"

*user presses Button1*

Text = "Add 15"    (This is as far as I've gotten)

*user presses Button1*

Text = "Multiply times 5"

*user presses Button1* etc. etc. etc.

If anybody could please explain or usher me in the right direction, I would be greatly appreciative.

Comment: I can see that people are simply voting my question down, so I'm guessing it's a trivial question, or it's unclear. Like I said, I'm very new to coding, and I just joined this site a few moments ago.  If somebody could tell me what's wrong with my question, that would be great also, thanks :-)

Comment: Shane , you can use button.setOnClickListener , or go to xml editor and define your click event method in onClick() , hope it helps

Comment: I think that the problem is a bit unclear (not a good reason to downvote, imho), since you say that you actually managed to change the text once!
Is your problem repeating the process for different texts? Can you add your code in the question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `button.setOnClickListener`

```
    public class MyActivity extends Activity {
     EditText et;
     Button button;
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         setContentView(R.layout.content_layout_id);
         et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);
         button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_id);
         button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 //Perform your Logic here.
                 et.setText("New text");
             }
         });
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer :-))

Comment: My reply was too long. I believe that I am up to that same point, now I would like to have it so that when user presses the button again, it changes the text again. Does that make sense?

Comment: Every time users click the button, setOnClickListener method works again.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a globle and a swithchcase

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
EditText et;

int CLICKS=0;

Button button;
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

 setContentView(R.layout.content_layout_id);
 et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);
 button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
 button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
            CLICKS++;
           switch(clicks)
          {
          case 1:
              et.setText("Pick a number");
          break;

          case 2:
              et.setText("Add 15");
          break;
         case 3:
              et.setText("Multiply times 5");
          break;
          }
     }
 });
}
}
```

Comment: This looks like what I tried to do but failed :-p  Thank you :-)

Comment: Sorry, been pulling my hair out since :-p

That worked, though I had to make int clicks final.
Thank you :-))